# winutils.copy in Python

Tags: python, copy

I try to copy a file in Python using winutils.copy. I don't want to use shutil.copy because I want to see the Windows progress bar.
My code:

`winutils.set my_path='001'`
`winutils.copy(src=r'C:\Users\IEUser\Documents\test.txt',dst=r'C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\%my_path%')`

The syntax error is 'Invalid Syntax'.
I can't find any documentation how to use this path or a variable with winutils.

Comment: Why are you taking the detour of setting my_path?

Comment: winutils.copy(src=r'C:\Users\IEUser\Documents\test.txt',dst=r'C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\001')    Does this work?

Comment: Yes that line works but what I tried is how I can use a variable in the destination path. So I like to try the directory 001 put in a variable and then use the variable in the path